# Remove-AzDeployment does not remove the resources created

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am creating a StorageAccount & Containers using ARM script

I use New-AzDeployment to create the resources. The resources are created properly. I want to remove the deployment

When I run Remove-AzDeployment -Name ; the deployment is removed, however the resources are not deleted.

How do I ensure that the resources are also deleted. I am using the new Az Module in powershell instead of the old Azure Module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Remove-AzDeployment cmdlet is used to remove a deployment from the deployment history. It won't remove resources deployed in this particular deployment.

You can remove resources from the resource group using Remove-AzResource, like this:

```
Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName | Remove-AzResource -Force
```